# Kubernetes - Cross AZ traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

Does anyone have any advice on how to minimize cross-az traffic for inter-pod communication when running Kubernetes in AWS? I want to keep my microservices pinned to the same availability zone so that microservice-a that resides in az-a will transmit it's payload to microservice-b also in az-a.

I know you can pin pods to a label and keep the traffic in the same AZ, but in addition to minimizing the cross az-traffic I also want to maintain HA by deploying to multiple AZs.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're willing to use alpha features you could use inter-pod affinity or node affinity rules to implement such a behaviour without loosing high availability.
You'll find details in the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/node-selection/)

Without that you could just have one deployment pinned to one node and a second deployment pinned to another node and one service which selects pods from both deployments - example code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42187265)